# Multiple single templates?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, page-template

Lets say i have a custom post type called 'event' that has several custom meta boxes for images, docs, etc..

Would it be possible to have two different single templates?

For example: 
i have a page that lists all events and if i click on an event, the single view shows me all the meta-info i put in event-single.php template.

now i want to have a different page that again lists all events, but if i click to view the single event, a different template is used, so i can show other meta-data connected with the event.

Or better:

```
page-events.php lists all events -> click on event -> shows single-event.php

page-media.php lists all events -> click on event -> shows single-event-whatever.php
```

Is this possible with WordPress?

Comment: I you have a custom post type, 'event', why do you want to list all event in a single template instead of using the archive template? Aside of this, the answer to your question is YES, it is possible with Wordpress.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure if my question was misleading: i absolutely do not list events in a single template. i just use a custom loop in a page-template and if i click on an event wordpress takes me to single-event.php.

Comment: A page template is still a single-post template (a page is post type). I would use the archive template for the list of events. Using a page is making extra work: one query to determine which page to show, one more to show the list of events. Using the archive template you only run one query, the unncesary query to dtermine the page won't be execute.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think your question meets the requirements of a "Work for me" format.

Comment: Well, i was asking because with my limited knowledge of wordpress i couldn't come up with a good solution to my problem. And just because you had a bad day does not mean you have the right to insult me. I have more the feeling you haven't read my question cause your answer wasn't dealing with my problem at all. See G.M's answer, that deals with the problem i'm having.

Comment: I read your question and it has this format: "I want this, it is possible?" with no sample code of what you are trying. I didn't insulted you, I'm sorry if you felt that, I just follow the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about about what topics can asked about in this site.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what your problem with me or my question is. I asked an on-topic question and got a very on-topic and specific reply. But please: let this very off-topic discussion go.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that when you list your events, you (most probably) use the `the_permalink()` function to get the url of the single event.

When this url is called, Wordpress show the single event, but how can Wordpress know if the link was clicked in the `page-events.php` or in the `page-media.php`?

If you don't say nothing to Wordpress (i.e. if you don't put information in the url) WP cannot distinguish if a link was clicked in a page or in other.

So, what I suggest you is to [add an endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

It means that you will have different url for your single event, e.g. if the standard link is something like `http://example.com/events/one-event/` you can have also `http://example.com/events/one-event/show/media` or `http://example.com/events/one-event/show/whatever`.

**`show` is the endpoint**, it means that a variable `show = media` or `show = whatever` is passed as query var to Wordpess and so you can make use of it to include the wanted template.

To add the endpoint use:

```
add_action('init', 'add_show_endpoint');

function add_show_endpoint() {
  add_rewrite_endpoint( 'show', EP_PERMALINK );
}
```

Now when you are in the `page-media.php` you should have link like `http://example.com/events/one-event/show/media` and when you are in `page-whatever.php` you should have links like `http://example.com/events/one-event/show/whatever`.

How to accomplish this? It's simple: add a filter on `get_permalink` function.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'set_event_permalink_filter');

function set_event_permalink_filter() {
  $single_templates = array(
    // page template => endpoint to use
    'page-media.php' => 'media',
    'page-info.php' => 'info',
    'page-whatever.php' => 'whatever'
  );
  foreach ( $single_templates as $page => $endpoint) {
    if ( is_page_template($page) ) {
      global $event_endpoint;
      $event_endpoint = $endpoint;
      add_filter('post_link', 'event_permalink', 99, 3);
      return;
    }
  }
}

function event_permalink ($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if ( $post->post_type != 'events' ) return $permalink;
  global $event_endpoint;
  if ( empty($event_endpoint) ) return $permalink;
  return user_trailingslashit($permalink) . 'show/' . $event_endpoint . '/';
}
```

This workflow is a bit more complex than it can be, because the `is_page_template()` conditional tag **doesn't** work *inside* the loop ([info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template#Cannot_Be_Used_Inside_The_Loop)), so we need to check page template before the loop start and use a global variable to pass the endpoint to the `event_permalink` function that is called by filter hook inside the loop.

At this point, if you go on the page, e.g. `page-media.php` all links generated for events post type end with `/show/media/` and when you click on them the query variable `show` is setted to `media`.

So, now we can hook into `template_include` filter and based on the `show` variable include the right template. For the pourpose we can use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to full support child themes.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'single_event_template');

function single_event_template( $template ) {
  if ( ! is_single('events') ) return $template;
  global $wp_query;
  $show = $wp_query->get('show');
  if ( empty($show) ) return $template;
  $file = locate_template( 'single-events-' . $show . '.php', true, false );
  return $file ? : $template;
}
```

So when we visit the link `http://example.com/events/one-event/show/media` (that is generated inside the `page-media.php`) if the template file `single-event-media.php` is found in parent or child theme it will be required, otherwise the standard `single-event.php` will be used.

Remember that after adding **all the code in this answer** to a plugin or in `functions.php` **you have to flush the rewrite rules** logging in your backend, going to *Settings->Permalinks* and clicking *Save Changes*.

Please note that code is **totally untested** and written here (with no syntax highlight), so it may contain typos and syntax errors: if you got some errors look in Codex (on php.net docs) for the code that trigger the error and check the right syntax.

In all the code is assumed your CPT is named 'events', change to fit your needs.

Also change the page templates to endpoint associations in the `$single_templates` variable inside `set_event_permalink_filter` function.

---

### Plugin Code

I've put all above code together in a plugin that use a class (avoiding the use of the global variable.

There are 2 static variables in the class you have to change to fit your needs.

The plugin also contain a filter: `'multiple_cpt_single_templates'` that allow adding page templates to endpoint associations from theme or from another plugin. You can even completely empty (set to `array()` ) the default `$single_templates` static variable and fill it via filter.

Being a plugin, I use the [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) to flush rewrite rules.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Multiple CPT Single Templates
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113878/multiple-single-templates
 * Author: G. M.
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/
 */

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'initMultipleCptSingleTemplates');

function initMultipleCptSingleTemplates() {
    MultipleCptSingleTemplates::init();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('MultipleCptSingleTemplates', 'install') );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array('MultipleCptSingleTemplates', 'uninstall') );

class MultipleCptSingleTemplates {

  /**
  * CHANGES FOLLOWING TWO VARIABLES ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS
  */

  static $cpt = 'events';

  static $single_templates =  array(
    // page template => endpoint to use
    'page-media.php' => 'media',
    'page-info.php' => 'info',
    'page-whatever.php' => 'whatever'
  );

  /** CONFIGIGURATION END */


  static $endpoint;

  static function init() {
    add_action('init', array( __CLASS__, 'add_show_endpoint') );
    add_filter('template_include', array( __CLASS__, 'single_event_template') );
    add_action('wp_head', array( __CLASS__, 'set_event_permalink_filter') );
  }

  static function add_show_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'show', EP_PERMALINK );
  }

  static function set_event_permalink_filter() {
    $single_templates = apply_filter('multiple_cpt_single_templates', self::$single_templates);
    if ( empty($single_templates) ) return;
    foreach ( $single_templates as $page => $endpoint) {
      if ( is_page_template($page) ) {
        self::$endpoint = $endpoint;
        add_filter('post_link', array( __CLASS__, 'event_permalink'), 99, 3);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  static function event_permalink ($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    if ( $post->post_type != self::$cpt ) return $permalink;
    if ( empty(self::$endpoint) ) return $permalink;
    return user_trailingslashit($permalink) . 'show/' . self::$endpoint . '/';
  }

  static function event_permalink ($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    if ( $post->post_type != self::$cpt ) return $permalink;
    if ( empty(self::$endpoint) ) return $permalink;
    return user_trailingslashit($permalink) . 'show/' . self::$endpoint . '/';
  }

  static  function install( $template ) {
    self::add_show_endpoint();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
  }

  static  function uninstall( $template ) {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
  }

}
```

Comment: Many many thanks for this, @G.M.! As a workaround to my problem i used a combination of `add_query_arg` in page-media.php and `get_template_part` in single-event.php. Nonetheless i try to incorporate your code in my project and update the answer/solution accordingly! Again, many thanks for this solution, this looks a lot better than my somewhat hackish workaround.